# Remap keyboard combinations, not just single registry values

Tags: windows, keyboard

I'm getting real tired of pressing shift every time I want to type `$` or `#`.  I've checked out key remapping programs like SharpKeys and a few others, but they don't support the `SHIFT+[key]` actions.  The problem is they modify the registry value for a single key only (I think).

I want to flip over my number keys so when I type `4`, it outputs `$`, similar to a French keyboard.  (I tried physically rotating the key so it's upside down, but that's not working).

There must be a solution for this - can you help?

Comment: Why close? This potentially increases the efficiency of one's keyboard use, particularly while programming. Incidentally, I was joking about rotating the key.  If I had phrased it along the lines of "How is the keyboard mapping on a French keyboard accomplished" it would obfuscate my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The registry hackers move virtual keys around.  What you need is a custom keyboard layout.  You can easily create your own with the [Microsoft KeyBoard Layout Creator utility](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/823010/the-microsoft-keyboard-layout-creator).

Comment: Checkmate, Hans.  Thanks very much, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Does not allow remapping a combination that involves Win-key :(

Comment: Here is an updated download link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer from @HansPassant, if you find trouble with the ctrl+KEY functions etc you might need to edit the `.klc` file manually.

See https://superuser.com/questions/171307/how-can-i-restore-ctrlkey-functionality-in-microsoft-keyboard-layout-creator :

> You need to modify the `.klc` file manually.
>
> Basically you just modify the `VK_` column to match the value in
>   column `1`.
>
> So for example if you want to bind <kbd>L</kbd> to <kbd>N</kbd>, you
>   would create the keyboard as you normally would in KLC. Then you would
>   open the KLC file in a text editor. Find the value `L` in the `VK_`
>   column, and switch it to an `N`.
>
> For more information, I wrote the [complete steps on my blog](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/08/how-to-fix-keyboard-shortcuts-in-klc-eg.html).